# Converting SQL datatable results into a JSON Object when using LEFT JOIN

Tags: c#, json, sql-server-2012

Could I please ask for some guidance as to how to achieve the following:

I have two tables. Table1 and Table 2.

Table1:

```
id  | Link    | Date
123 | Example | 01/01/2017
```

Table2:

```
id  | Description              | Name | Email
123 | Example edges on corners | Jim  | Jim@example.com
123 | damage to corner         | Fred | Fred@example,com
```

I am using an SQL statement to join table 2 to table 1. Then converting the results into a JSON Object.

**C# code**

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.Link, Table1.Date, Table2.Description, Table2.Name, Table2.Email FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                Dictionary<string, object> row;
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        if (col.ColumnName == "Link")
                        {
                            string escapeChar = dr[col].ToString().Replace(@"\", @"");
                            row.Add(col.ColumnName, escapeChar);
                        }
                        else if (col.ColumnName == "Date")
                        {
                            DateTime formatDate = DateTime.Parse(dr[col].ToString());
                            row.Add(col.ColumnName, formatDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                        }

                    }
                    rows.Add(row);
                }
                return serializer.Serialize(rows);
            }
        }
```

The Results is:

```
[
  {
    "ID": "123",
    "Link": "example",
    "Date":"01/01/2017",
    "Description": "round edges on corners",
    "Name": "Jim",
    "Email": "Jim@example.com"
  },
  {
    "ID": "123",
    "Link": "example",
    "Date":"01/01/2017",
    "Description": "damage to corner",
    "Name": "Fred",
    "Email": "Fred@example,com"
  }
]
```

What I need is:

```
[
  {
    "ID": "123",
    "Link": "example",
    "Date": "01\/01\/2017",
    "Descriptions": [
      {
        "Description": "round edges on corners",
        "Name": "Jim",
        "Email": "Jim@example.com"
      },
      {
        "Description": "round edges on corners ",
        "Name": "Fred",
        "Email": " Fred @example.com"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Essentially there are two entries in Table2 for ID 123 in Table1. How can I achieve the above result? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please tag your DBMS.

Comment: The JavaScriptSerializer doesn't give you much control. I would suggest using JSON.NET and [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CreatingLINQtoJSON.htm) to allow you to produce the specific JSON you need directly (serialisers make easy cases easy, but if you need a specific format they are much header than doing it yourself).

Comment: spot on thank you for the link I will try that approach

Answer (score 1):

You may use SQL Server 2016+ JSON features

```
SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.Link, Table1.Date, 
  (
     SELECT Table2.Description, Table2.Name, Table2.Email 
     FROM Table2
     WHERE Table1.ID = Table2.ID 
     FOR json auto
  ) as 'Descriptions' 
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.ID, Table1.Link, Table1.Date
FOR json auto
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, is this to replace current select statement?

Comment: @user3515765 exactly and it should return the result in the JSON format you described in your question.

Comment: I am getting an error with this code System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near 'json'.

Comment: @user3515765 what DBMS are you using? JSON is available in SQL Server since 2016.

Comment: I am using MSMS 2016 server is 2012. It doesnt like 'json auto'